Finding $\lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{x^3f(\mathbf{u})}{f(x)\sin^3 \mathbf{u}}$ via Taylor remainder formula
Assume that the second derivative of the function $f(x)$ is continuous, and $f''(x)>0$, $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=0$, find the limit: $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3f(u)}{f(x)\sin^3u}$, where $\mathbf{u}$ is the x-intercept of the tangent line to the curve $y=f(x)$ at point $P(x,f(x))$.
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{u}(x)=x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}.
\end{align*}
First I multiplied an expression with a limit of 1, then simplified the original limit
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^3x}{x^3}=\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^3=\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x}{1}\right)^3=1.
\end{align*}
So let $x=\mathbf{u}(x)$ then
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^3\mathbf{u}}{\mathbf{u}^3}=1.
\end{align*}
So the original limit is
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3f(\mathbf{u})}{f(x)\sin^3\mathbf{u}}=
\lim_{x\to0}1\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3f(\mathbf{u})}{f(x)\sin^3\mathbf{u}}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^3\mathbf{u}}{\mathbf{u}^3}\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3f(\mathbf{u})}{f(x)\sin^3\mathbf{u}}=
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3f(\mathbf{u})}{\mathbf{u}^3f(x)}
\end{align*}
Next I try to solve $\frac{x^3}{\mathbf{u}^3}$ and $\frac{f(\mathbf{u})}{f(x)}$ separately:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^3}{\mathbf{u}^3}=&
\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\mathbf{u}}\right)^3. \\
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\mathbf{u}}=&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{1-\frac{f(x)}{xf'(x)}} \\
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{xf'(x)}=&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)}{xf''(x)+f'(x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f''(x)}{xf'''(x)+2f''(x)}
\end{align*}
Since I was not sure if the third derivative of $f(x)$ existed, I turned to solving for another one.
Using Taylor formula with Lagrangian remainder:
\begin{align*}
f(\mathbf{u})=&f(0)+f'(0)\mathbf{u}+\frac{1}{2}c_1^2f''(0) \\
f(x)=&f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{1}{2}c_2^2f''(0) \\
\end{align*}
$c_1$ is between $0$ and $\mathbf{u}$, $c_2$ is between $0$ and $x$.
So the limit can be:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(\mathbf{u})}{f(x)}=\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{c_1}{c_2}\right)^2
\end{align*}
I was blocked again.
Someone showed a video showing that the limit is $2$ in this case. He used a similar approach to mine, but used the Peano form of the remainder formula and infinitesimals. I found this irrational and confusing because he used the cubic Peano remainder, $o(x^2)$. I don't think that continuity of the second derivative gives me direct information about the third derivative.
help me pls.

Why $f(x) > 0 \text{ but } f(0) = 0$? I think it must be more clear. And why $\lim_{x \to{0}} u(x)$ converges?

@Charles Green Thank you for your timely correction.Problem conditions have been corrected.

For the limit to be equal to the claimed value $2$, $f$ should also be twice-differentiable at $0$ with $f''(0) > 0$, otherwise the limit can be various values, e.g., $f(x)=x^a$ with $a>2$.

Minor typesetting point: It is very unusual to use \mathbf for scalar quantities. Usually that would be reserved for vectors (or something else special)
